# LDAP custom authentication filter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-ldap

I have a custom authentication CustomAuthenticationProvider class which does a  authenticate the user by hitting LDAP remote server. I managed to create and configure the custom authentication provider but having trouble to call  doAuthentication method which is defined in SecurityConfiguration.

```
@Component 
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
private final Logger log=LoggerFactory.getLogger(CustomAuthenticationProvider.class);

@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

    String username = authentication.getName();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    if (username == null) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("User is not found");
    }

    if (password == null) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException("Password is not found");
    }

    try {
        LdapContextSource ldapContextSource = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapContextSource.setUrl("ldap://jnj.com:3268");
        ldapContextSource.setBase("dc=jnj,dc=com");
        ldapContextSource.setUserDn(username);
        ldapContextSource.setPassword(password);
        try {
            // initialize the context
            ldapContextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        LdapTemplate ldapTemplate = new LdapTemplate(ldapContextSource);
        ldapTemplate.afterPropertiesSet();

       // ldapTemplate.setIgnorePartialResultException(true); // Active Directory doesn’t transparently handle referrals. This fixes that.
        AndFilter filter = new AndFilter();
        filter.and(new EqualsFilter("sAMAccountName", username));

        try {
            boolean authed = ldapTemplate.authenticate("", filter.toString(), password);
            log.debug("Auuthenticated : "+authed);
        } catch (org.springframework.ldap.AuthenticationException ee) {
//userDisplay.setText(“Invalid Username/Password”);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities = Collections.singleton(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password, authorities);

     return  authenticationToken;
   // return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username,password);

}



@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
}
```

**This method is called in SecurityConfiguration,I need to bind this method to mine CustomAuthenticationProvider class**

```
 @Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
    try {
             auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider)
             .ldapAuthentication().userDetailsContextMapper(userDetailsContextMapper())
            .ldapAuthoritiesPopulator(ldapAuthoritiesPopulator()).userSearchBase(USER_SEARCH_BASE)
            .userSearchFilter(USER_SEARCH_FILTER).groupSearchBase(GROUP_SEARCH_BASE)
            .groupSearchFilter(GROUP_SEARCH_FILTER).contextSource(contextSource());

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new BeanInitializationException("Security configuration failed", e);
    }
}
```

**This method I need to call for LDAP**

```
 protected DirContextOperations doAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken auth) {
        String username = auth.getName();
        String password = (String) auth.getCredentials();

        DirContext ctx = bindAsUser(username, password);

        try {
            return searchForUser(ctx, username);
        } catch (NamingException e) {
            log.error("Failed to locate directory entry for authenticated user: " + username, e);
            throw badCredentials(e);
        } finally {
            LdapUtils.closeContext(ctx);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you need a custom auth provider at all? Only Active Directory allows to authenticate a user via an attribute, here 'samAccountName'. This is not LDAP compliant.

Comment: @BernhardThalmayr actually,I am trying to integrate LDAP authentication in Spring Boot but not able to do so i think something configure is missing

Comment: If you are using Microsoft AD (which behaves differently than an LDAPv3 Directory Server) you could use the ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider. I you don't  use AD but an LDAPv3 Directory Server you could use LdapAuthenticationProvider with the BindAuthenticator. It doesn't matter that this is Spring Boot.

AD would also work with the latter, but then you can not use the so called 'userPrincipalName' (samAccountName@AD-domain) as "LoginID."